# beamer with \index creates empty lines in the index

Tags: beamer, indexing

I try to build an index in two columns at the end of my slides. To do so, I use the definitions from [Create index entries in beamer with 2 columns (latex-community.org)](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=11993):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 
\newenvironment{theindex} 
 {\let\item\par %definitions for subitem etc 
 }{} 
\newcommand\indexspace{} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{test 1} 
\index{Laplace}Laplace transform is... \LaTeXe\ can make you happy! 
\index{Test} 
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}{test 2} 
\printindex \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

However, sometimes the index entry including the page numbers fits in one line, but nevertheless LaTeX makes an empty line after the entry. It looks pretty ugly... What can I do to avoid the empty lines?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Also note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: It looks fine with me. Please, run 1) `pdflatex`, 2) `pdflatex` again, 3) `makeindex`, and post the contents of `.idx` and `.ind` files.